# Overflow and Text-overflow within fieldsets

Tags: html, css

Here's a working example (in webkit browsers, at least) of overflow and text-overflow working to truncate long text when you shrink the browser width:

```
<div>short</div>
<div style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;">loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</div>
<div>short</div>
<div>short</div>
<div>short</div>
```

But, if I wrap those divs in a fieldset the truncate no longer happens. Any ideas on additional styling I need to add?

Broken example:

```
<fieldset>
  <div>short</div>
  <div style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</div>
  <div>short</div>
  <div>short</div>
  <div>short</div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is due to [weird behavior with `fieldset`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17408815/1959975), and [the fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17863685/1959975) is to change certain CSS properties that browsers set to weird values. For instance, this example also makes the `legend` get cut off nicely. It works in Chrome for me but you may need to read through [the fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17863685/1959975) to see how to get it working in other browsers too.

```css
fieldset
{
    min-width: 0;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
legend
{
    min-width: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<fieldset><legend>This is due to weird behavior with fieldsets, and the fix is to change certain CSS properties that browsers set to weird values.</legend><span>This is a loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong line of text that would normally overflow or cause the fieldset to widen and overflow itself.</span></fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you for this - setting `min-width: 0` and `display: table-cell` on the `fieldset` fixed this in Chrome and Firefox, respectively. See link to "the fix" in the answer.

Comment: Interestingly it works within the code snippet but not within my website, with exact copy-paste…

Comment: `min-width: 0;` - I hope you're wearing a cape because you're a hero.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you add a fixed width to `fieldset`, for example `<fieldset style="width: 500px">`. Would that be enough? Percentage widths don't seem to work.

Comment: That's one work-around I found, but there should theoretically be a way to do it without setting the width, since I need to also handle resize events.