# overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; not working inside fieldset?

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with the use of `white-space: nowrap;` inside a `fieldset` in both Google Chrome and Firefox (IE behaves as I want).

What I would like to happen is that just a single line of text is displayed with any excess being hidden and an elipsis added. This works in all three of the browsers I mention when my `div` is outside the `fieldset` but breaks as soon as I move it inside.

The screenshot below shows both "working" and "not working" cases.

[image: Screenshot]

The bottom `div` (outside the `fieldset`) has the effect that I want of text truncation rather than div expansion.

Why is this happening and what do I need to do to prevent it?

The HTML related to the screenshot is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #ccc;">
    <form action="">
    <div id="outer" style="background-color: #fff; width: 50%">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Foo</legend>
            <div style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi posuere, elit id
                lobortis ultricies, mi velit dictum libero, pharetra dapibus libero lectus vel nibh.
                Mauris sem dolor, auctor vitae accumsan lacinia, rhoncus non mauris. Morbi ac mi
                eros, eu pretium massa. </div>
        </fieldset>
         <div style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi posuere, elit id
                lobortis ultricies, mi velit dictum libero, pharetra dapibus libero lectus vel nibh.
                Mauris sem dolor, auctor vitae accumsan lacinia, rhoncus non mauris. Morbi ac mi
                eros, eu pretium massa. </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Per [another question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7434846/103842), the `fieldset` must have a width set in order for this to work. By setting the width everything works correctly.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3Q3p/58/) to see the difference.

Comment: hmm your fiddle is showing my error not solving it?  But I think you should be right!

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly,you should use `word-wrap: break-word;` instead of `white-space: nowrap;` i didnt test my code but I am sure it will work check demo http://jsfiddle.net/u3Q3p/1/

Comment: Your demo fiddle wraps the text onto multiple lines in all three browsers. I only want to display one line of text and have that line truncated at the right hand side rather than expanding the div indefinitely.

Comment: Checking the fiddle - there are multiple lines, but all but the last one are outside the `<div>` element with the appropriate styling. This works for me.